# Unable to create Facebook app even after passing phone verification

Tags: android, facebook

When I apply for a Facebook app on http://www.facebook.com/developers, it tells me to add my phone number for user verification, but even after I pass the phone check I'm still not able to create my app. Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be many problems with the authentication process. Check this out: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=60622&p=11
or
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=30740&p=13

Comment: oh!..i see it! does it means what i can do is waiting ?wait for the FB managers to fix it? i do not have a cc ,i just work for months... thank you for your answer...thanks.

Comment: FYI, both links are dead.